# how do I change the Ticks color and gridline color of chatsJs according to my theme Dark/Light?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the color of my lables and gridlines according to theme.. this is my code to change theme

```
function mystylesheet () { console.log(currentTheme) if(checkBox.checked){
document.getElementById("mystylesheet").setAttribute('href', "css/theme/dark.css");  
window.localStorage.setItem('data-theme', 'dark'); } else  {
document.getElementById("mystylesheet").setAttribute('href', "css/theme/light.css")   
window.localStorage.setItem('data-theme', 'light'); }  changeImage(); }
```

this is to change Tick color or lable color in chatjs

```
var lableColor = 'black'; //Lables color     if(currentTheme === 'dark'){  lableColor = 'white';}else{lableColor = 'black'}
```

now the only problem hea is that it is changing after refreshing the page not instantly new to web dev... how do I achieve this

```
options:{
scales:{
 y:{
     ticks:{
         color: 'lableColor'
         
     }
 },
 x: {
     
     ticks:{
         color: 'lableColor'
        
     }
   }
}
```

}

Comment: how is the variable `lableColor` at all realted to anything at all? it's a javascript variable that has nothing to do with CSS - consider having the stylesheet change the label color

Comment: sorry i missed out where i have use lableColor its in chartsJs m updating the question again

Comment: still, shouldn't the stylesheet be responsible for styling?

Comment: Yes exactly.. but the problem hea is am using a canvas card inside that m adding ChartsJs thats is the reason i cannot style it

Comment: @Bravo I have updated the question the Tick color is what i want to change according to theme because its not visible I want it black when the theme is light and vice versa it is changing but only after refreshing the page.. i want it dynamically

Comment: I guess once you change themes you'll need to **redraw** the "canvas card"

Comment: @Bravo I dont understand " Redraw " am new to coding and development

Comment: I don't know what a canvas card is, so I assume it's a canvas you draw on. so, redraw means to draw again

Comment: @Bravo Bootstrap element Canvas and inside that is chartsjs.. that is reason I cannot draw it..